I am facing this issue on porter , meanwhile i have properly runable code on localhost, I have also added the key elements in requirements.txt
ERROR:app:Exception on /test_ml [GET]

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 997, in async_to_sync
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Install Flask with the 'async' extra in order to use async views.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: RuntimeError: Install Flask with the 'async' extra in order to use async views. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
